# how can i come back to my app from map app?

Tags: ios

I am switching to map app from my app to show the location,can some one guide me how can I come back to my app.Here is the code I am using

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];  
[app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Paris"]];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't! As far as I know (until iOS 5.0).
Instead you can embed the map using mapkit in your app.

So basically as of now there is now way to ask other apps (Safari, Map, mail, photos, or any other app for that mater) to hand it back to you (return the control to you).

The solution is to embed their services into your app using published API, almost all Apple apps have this, like the mail (`MFMailComposeViewController` in `<MessageUI/MessageUI.h>`
), or map (mapkit), or Camera API ...  any many popular 3rd party apps also have some way of helping you achieve this, either by providing libraries or using the Apple provided facilities.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Especially Apps like Mail or Safari can call back your App by using a custom URL scheme. Your App has to register and implement a custom URL scheme and whenever such URL is activated, your App gets called.

Comment: That is "calling your application" usually when user taps on a link that trigger yours, we are here talking about "calling back", user is in your app then they are sent to map by your app and you want them to be "sent back" to your app when they are done.

Comment: Right, Javascript would do that for you when embedded within a document displayed by a Webbrowser or a Mail-Client.